Find $n$ using the Chebyshev Inequality

A sample of size $n$ with sample mean $\bar{X}_n$ is drawn from the uniform distribution on interval $(0,1)$. Find $n$ such that $P(\frac{-1}{10} \lt \bar{X}_n - \frac{1}{2} \lt \frac{1}{10})\ge 0.9$

It makes sense to use the Chebyshev Inequality:
$$P(|\bar{X}_n-\mu|\ge t)\le \frac{\sigma^2}{nt^2}$$
Applying this,
$$P(|\bar{X}_n - \frac{1}{2}| \lt \frac{1}{10})\le 1-\frac{(1/12)^2}{n(1/10)^2}=0.9\implies n=(0.1*0.01*144)^{-1}\approx 7$$
Does this seem correct?

As Amir has spotted, in your computation $\frac{\color{red}{(1/12)^2}}{n(1/10)^2}$ needs to be replaced by $\frac{1/12}{n(1/10)^2}$ as the variance of $X\sim \mathcal U (0,1)$ is $1/12$. This gives $n\ge 84$ using Chebyshev's inequality.
In this particular case of the Bates distribution,  when $n=7$ you will find that $P(-\frac{1}{10} \lt \bar X - \frac{1}{2} \lt \frac{1}{10})$  is near $0.63$,  which is clearly far too small.  Amir's correction to $n =84$ or more is larger than necessary for this particularly distribution and gives a probability over $0.99$.
The distribution is reasonably well approximated by the normal distribution when $n$ is not tiny.  For a normal distribution  with mean $\frac12$ and variance $\frac1{12n}$ you can find $P(-\frac{1}{10} \lt Y - \frac{1}{2} \lt \frac{1}{10})= 0.9$ when $n= \frac1{12}\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(0.95)}{1/10}\right)^2 \approx 22.546$.  So $n\ge 23$ would be a better answer.
To illustrate this with a simulation using R, suggesting $23$ is around the correct cuttoff:
set.seed(2024)

xbarsim <- function(n){ mean(runif(n)) }

xbar <- replicate(10^6, xbarsim(7))           # n=7
mean(-1/10 < xbar - 1/2 & xbar - 1/2 < 1/10)
# 0.63311

xbar <- replicate(10^6, xbarsim(22))          # n=22
mean(-1/10 < xbar - 1/2 & xbar - 1/2 < 1/10)
# 0.895525

xbar  <- replicate(10^6, xbarsim(23))          # n=23
mean(-1/10 < xbar - 1/2 & xbar - 1/2 < 1/10) 
# 0.903014

xbar  <- replicate(10^6, xbarsim(84))          # n=84
mean(-1/10 < xbar - 1/2 & xbar - 1/2 < 1/10) 
# 0.998559


Please check my answer. The OP's method seems correct, but the wrong condition $n\ge7$ is obtained since  $1/144$ is used instead of $1/12$.

@Amir That is a good point - I will adjust my answer. Your corrected answer of $n\ge 84$ is loose (as Chebyshev's inequality often is).

I just added the key point in my answer to your answer and removed mine to have one good answer.
